# WPF: Xaml, create an observable collection<object> in xaml in .NET 4.0

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, observablecollection

[the web site](http://www.wpftutorial.net/XAML2009.html) says you can in .NET 4.0

I cant seem to do it though, what assesmbly references and xmlns' do i need

the following does not work

```
xmlns:coll="clr-namespace:System.Collections.ObjectModel;assembly=mscorlib"

<coll:ObservableCollection x:TypeArguments="x:Object">
    <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut"/>
    <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy"/>
    <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste"/>
</coll:ObservableCollection>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[ObservableCollection<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) is defined in the **System** assembly, so your namespace should read:

```
xmlns:coll="clr-namespace:System.Collections.ObjectModel;assembly=System"
```

You can find that information in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) at the top where it says:

**Namespace:** System.Collections.ObjectModel
**Assembly:** System (in System.dll)
**XMLNS for XAML:** Not mapped to an xmlns.

Note that the *assembly has changed between v3.5 and v4.0*. In v3.5 it was defined in the WindowsBase assembly. However, this was a drawback since you often would like to use the class without any WPF assemblies referenced. So maybe that is why they changed it.

Furthermore, you should also check [this blog post](http://blogs.windowsclient.net/rob_relyea/archive/2009/05/20/yes-xaml2009-isn-t-everywhere-yet.aspx), which says that the new XAML features are not completely available in VS yet!

Comment: I tried this but then I get a blue squiggly saying `The name "ObservableCollection" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:System.Collections.ObjectModel;assembly=System".`. Using the `ObservableCollection` in code DOES work indeed.

Answer (score 11):

I just came across the same problem while working on a Windows Store App. After several problems I figured out that the easiest why to define such a collection in XAML is to simply create a subclass:

```
namespace my.name.space {
    public class ObservableMyObjectCollection: ObservableCollection<MyObject> {
    }
}
```

And then use it like so

```
<local:ObservableMyObjectCollection
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:my.name.space">

   <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut"/>
   <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy"/>
   <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste"/>

<local:ObservableMyObjectCollection>
```