# how to declare ObservableCollecion in Silverlight Xaml

Tags: silverlight, xaml, namespaces, .net-assembly

I want to add declarations for a Object with type of ObservableCollection in Silverlight Xaml. This is what I have done.

1.Add the xmlns declaration like this:

```
xmlns:col="clr-namespace:System.Collections.ObjectModel;assembly=System.Windows"
```

2.Add the ObservableCollection declaration like this:

```
    <col:ObservableCollection x:TypeArguments="sys:String" x:Key="AnaBase">
        <sys:String>string1</sys:String>
        <sys:String>string2</sys:String>
        <sys:String>string3</sys:String>
    </col:ObservableCollection>
```

3.The above code works fine in Vs2010 editor because it doesn't report any errors.

The problem is, when I try to build such xaml it always outputs error such as
 "The tag 'ObservableCollection' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:System.Collections.ObjectModel;assembly=System.Windows'."
It seems to me that the namespace resolvers in editing and building of VS work in different ways. Could anyone please to explain this phenomenon to me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found out the answer. The generics is not supported in Silverlight 4. That's why ObservableCollection can't be seen in Intellisense of XAML.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: [WPF: Xaml, create an observable collection<object> in xaml in .NET 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695847/wpf-xaml-create-an-observable-collectionobject-in-xaml-in-net-4-0)

Comment: Priyank, thank you very much for your reply. But unfortunately that answer doesn't work in my case. Because in Silverlight the class ObservableCollection is defined in System.Windows.dll, not in System.dll.