# How to declare ObservableCollection namespace in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to use the ObservableCollection class in Net 4.5 using the xaml.

This is how I specify the namespace in the xaml:

```
xmlns:coll="clr-namespace:System.Collections.ObjectModel;assembly=System"
```

And the collection declaration is like this:

```
<ic:MyControl.Resources>
    <coll:ObservableCollection x:TypeArguments="commands:Command" x:Key="CommandCollection"/>
</ic:MyControl.Resources>
```

I get this compile error:

> The tag 'ObservableCollection' does not exist in XML namespace
>   'clr-namespace:System.Collections.ObjectModel;assembly=System'.

I think the assembly name may be incorrect, but a search on forums here said it is the System assembly. Can anyone tell me what's going wrong?

Comment: Are you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695847/wpf-xaml-create-an-observable-collectionobject-in-xaml-in-net-4-0 ?

Comment: If you are declaring this in a WPF control that will be compiled to Baml, then you are stuck with the Xaml2006 language spec, and you cannot use `x:TypeArguments` anywhere but in the root element.  Xaml2009 allows it to be used anywhere, but you can only use Xaml2009 for Xaml files that you load manually at runtime.

Comment: What's the point to keep `ObservableCollection<T>` in the view, moreover, in the view's resources? Something going wrong with your code.

Answer (score 3):

From the Remarks section in the [ObservableCollection documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx):

> Notes on XAML Usage
>
> ObservableCollection can be used as a XAML object element in
>   Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF), in versions 3.0 and 3.5.
>   However, the usage has substantial limitations.
>
> ...
>
> A more straightforward way to use ObservableCollection capabilities
>   from XAML in an application is to declare your own non-generic custom
>   collection class that derives from ObservableCollection, and
>   constrains it to a specific type. Then map the assembly that contains
>   this class, and reference it as an object element in your XAML.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer above.  However, you could go further than that and just expose your collection as a CollectionViewSource in the resource and bind to that, and then have your source collection as an ObservableCollection in your ViewModel.  Details of CollectionViewSource can be found here.

[CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)