# WPF Attached Property unable to specify Changed Callback for collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, attached-properties

**EDIT:**
In order to clear up all confusions with instanct-closing as duplicates. Please see point (3.) explaining why the accepted answer does not apply. In short, the linked answer is fine as long as you are not using XAML to set the value because XAML will **never** call `PropertyChangedCallback` because it **re-uses** the default instance.

---

**Question:**
Considering a simple WPF's *Attached Property* of `ObservableCollection<T>` type with XAML-defined value:

```
// public static class MyCollectionExetension.cs
public static ObservableCollection<int> GetMyCollection(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (ObservableCollection<int>)obj.GetValue(MyCollectionProperty);
}

public static void SetMyCollection(DependencyObject obj, ObservableCollection<int> value)
{
    obj.SetValue(MyCollectionProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCollectionProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyCollection", typeof(ObservableCollection<int>), 
    typeof(MyCollectionExetension), new PropertyMetadata(null);

public static void DoThisWhenMyCollectionChanged(DependencyObejct assignee, IEnumerable<int> newValues) {
   // how can I invoke this?
}

//UserControl.xaml
<Grid xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <b:DataGridExtensions.MyCollection >
        <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
        <sys:Int32>2</sys:Int32>
    </b:DataGridExtensions.MyCollection>
</Grid>
```

How can I hook collection changed events with access to the both the `DependencyObject` it is attached to and the new items? MyCollection *must* be definable in XAML.
It seems simple at first, but none of following worked for me:

1. Set callback `new UIPropertyMetadata(null, CollectionChanged)` causes crash:

> XamlObjectWriterException: 'Collection property 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid'.'MyCollection' is null.'

2. OK, let's provide default value in order to avoid the crash above: `new UIPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<int>(), CollectionChanged)`
   That, however prevent `CollectionChanged` from ever firing due to XAML not instantiating new collection but rather adding items to existing collection.
3. Fixing the above and hook `CollectionChanged` while providing default value `new UIPropertyMetadata(ProvideWithRegisteredCollectionChanged(), CollectionChanged)`does not work neither because there is no way to pass the `DependencyProperty` to `ProvideWithRegisteredCollectionChanged()` method due to being in static context.
4. Coalescing in `MyCollection` either in `GetMyCollection()` getter or `CoerceValueCallback` does not prevent the crash from point 1. above since it does not seem to be called before property is first accessed.

Comment: Also take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15023687/1136211

Comment: That doesn't matter. The point is that you have to attach a CollectionChanged event handler in the PropertyChangedCallback.

Comment: This has nothing to do with dependency property vs attached property. The `CollectionChanged` callback (`DependencyPropertyChangedCallback`) is only invoked when the dependency property gets a new collection assigned. Inside the `ColectionChanged` callback you have to subscribe to the `MyCollection.CollectionChanged` event too to get notified when the actual collection (and not only the property) has changed.

Comment: @Clemens sorry, my mistake but the answer still does not apply, please see edit - if you set the value in XAML, it would *re-use* default value rather than instantiating new `ObservaleCollection<int>` and because of that the `PropertyChangedCallback` will never be called in first place (and answer is *is* called once), it I will never give me the chance to register `NotifyCollectionChanged`. Alternatively, if you still do not trust me the answer does apply, please do try the provided example with answer aplied (point 3. of what I tried).

Comment: Afaik there is no way to safely provide a non-null default value for a collection-type attached property. You would have to do an explicit collection instance creation in XAML: `<b:DataGridExtensions.MyCollection><YourCollectionType>... elements ... </YourCollectionType></b:DataGridExtensions.MyCollection>`

Comment: @Clemens in case if I do not try to provide default value, how do I avoid the problem `null` causing `XamlObjectWriterException`  (i.e. "what I tried point 1.")?

Comment: You would have to make an explicit collection instance creation in XAML: `<b:DataGridExtensions.MyCollection><YourCollectionType>... elements ... </YourCollectionType></b:DataGridExtensions.MyCollection>`

Comment: If you provide a collection in XAML like this, why is it an ObservableCollection? Do you ever add or remove elements later?

Comment: @Clemens while not absolutely necessary, it would be nice to be defined of items changing. I would prefer to avoid to the bloat (and headache of correctly derving collections) of `class MyCollectionCollection : ObservableCollection<int>` but using `ObservableCollection<int>` directly does not seem to be possible in XAML.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/2695847/1136211. It won't compile in my system however...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196460/discussion-between-wondra-and-clemens).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't correctly assign a non-null default value for a collection-type attached property. Hence you have to create an instance in XAML.

Since declaring an ObservableCollection directly in XAML seems not easily possible, declare an appropriate derived type:

```
public class MyCollection : ObservableCollection<int>
{
}
```

and create an instance in XAML like this:

```
<Grid>
    <b:MyCollectionExtension.MyCollection>
        <b:MyCollection>
            <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>2</sys:Int32>
        </b:MyCollection>
    </b:MyCollectionExtension.MyCollection>
</Grid>
```

The attached property declaration should look like shown below, including the code that attaches and detaches a `CollectionChanged` event handler.

```
public static class MyCollectionExtension
{
    public static MyCollection GetMyCollection(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (MyCollection)obj.GetValue(MyCollectionProperty);
    }

    public static void SetMyCollection(DependencyObject obj, MyCollection value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(MyCollectionProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCollectionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "MyCollection",
            typeof(MyCollection),
            typeof(MyCollectionExtension),
            new PropertyMetadata(MyCollectionPropertyChanged));

    public static void MyCollectionPropertyChanged(
        DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var oldCollection = e.OldValue as MyCollection;
        var newCollection = e.NewValue as MyCollection;

        if (oldCollection != null)
        {
            oldCollection.CollectionChanged -= MyCollectionChanged;
        }
        if (newCollection != null)
        {
            newCollection.CollectionChanged += MyCollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    public static void MyCollectionChanged(
        object o, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```