# XAML color struct declaration by name

Tags: wpf, xaml, colors

I have an `ObservableCollection<Color>` dependency property in my CustomControl, which I want to parametrize on each instantiation, preferably in XAML:

```
            <clb:ColorListBox.StandardColors>
                <local:ObservableColorCollection>
                    <Color R=255 G=0 B=0 />
                    <Color ... /
                </local:ObservableColorCollection>                    
            </clb:ColorListBox.StandardColors>
```

How can I declare the colors by name?

(Btw: the ObservableColorCollection is defined [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22017289/9963147) way in the codebehind)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the [answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.color)

```
            <clb:ColorListBox.StandardColors>
                <local:ObservableColorCollection>
                    <Color>Red</Color>
                    <Color>Green</Color>
                    <Color>Blue</Color>
                    <Color>#8F8F8F</Color>
                </local:ObservableColorCollection>                    
            </clb:ColorListBox.StandardColors>
```